# Does anybody can simulate fluid library (Modelica)

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have only one question. Can somebody simulate a heatexchanger example from Modelica standart library with OpenModelica? Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.HeatExchangerSimulation.
There are so many errors when I have tried to simulate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openmodelica does not yet run all of the Modelica Standard Library.  They seem to be working towards that, and they are constantly testing what works.
You can see the current status here:
[MSL Coverage](https://test.openmodelica.org/libraries/MSL_3.2.1/BuildModelRecursive.html)

And, that also shows that HeatExchangerSimulation example doesn't yet work.